# can i use ruby on rails get and post for the same method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http

I'm new to web development in general and ruby on rails in specific. I'm working on developing a web interface where i'm using a 'Get' and 'Post' requests on the same method. When i use a get method and send parameters (like username and password), they are being visible in the url. Hence, below is what i did.

form1.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :modify, :method => "post", :url => {:action => "method2"} do |f|%>
#code here to input username and password
<%=end%>
```

in my routes.rb i wrote the following routes to the method2:

```
post 'controller/method2'
get 'controller/method2'
```

When i enter `username and password` and click on submit, it is finding the `post 'method2'` and executing the code in the controller, and displaying `method2.html.erb` as there is a `get request` for the same method and also there is a view for method2.

However, i suspect this is not the right way to do it. I do not want the password to be visible. I came to know that i have two options, store the password in a session or send a post request. I do not want to store in session as it is not safe. When i write a post method the page expires when the user tries to come back. To prevent either of these happening, i used the same action in controller as post and get and now i do not see any parameters visible in the url.

Please let me know if this is not the right way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you should have this :

```
render 'controller/method2'
```

And you should have a file in this path :

```
app/views/controller/method2.html.erb
```

You don't need to have two routes.

Comment: I'm rendering method2.html.erb already and everything is working fine. But i'm not comfortable with the way i'm doing it and i think there are better ways to do the same as citraL said in the below answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solid method for manipulating user & password, I recommend you go through the [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org), it's an excellent tutorial and it will learn you the basics to start with Rails programming, including a safe username/password use.

Alternatively, you can use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/), which is a very popular gem for this purpose.

I would not try to implement a secure user/password system without really knowing what you are doing...

Comment: The project i'm working currently is for internal purposes and i was told that currently i need not worry about security issues. So i was just trying to get it done. But, i will try to implement what you said as soon as possible. Thank you